# Python pandas to_csv() - 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to export my dataframe to a `.csv` file, I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-1091aca305ff> in <module>()
----> 1 df.to_csv('result.csv')

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

When I make one column as a series and use `to_csv`, it works.

My `df` consists of `speechID`, `words_counts` ... something like that.

How can I export my results to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you please add your DataFrame and the full traceback of your error?

Comment: make sure to put the full pathway where you want your file to go `df.to_csv(r'C:\path_to_file\file.csv')`